# Buttons for website

Tags: html, css, graphics

I need to create some buttons for a web app. However, I have no graphics/Photoshop skills at all. Is there a website/software out there that I can simply enter the text for my button and it will spit out a graphical image with those words on top?

I don't mind avoiding graphics altogether, but the links must look like a button. e.g. a box. The buttons on Stackoverflow look too plain for my tastes.

Comment: yes, there are. Google is your friend...

Comment: Take a look at http://www.zurb.com/article/266/super-awesome-buttons-with-css3-and-rgba

Comment: careful buster, i know where you live :D :D thanks for going through my profile and downvoting my questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Google's approach to buttons](http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html).

They are created out of HTML elements rather than being graphics.  The main advantage of doing it this way is that you can create a nice looking button with any text on the fly, which is good if you have lots of buttons or lots of languages to display your site in.

Comment: +1 True to the motto: If Google does it, anyone can do it ;)

Comment: View Source on this - http://stopdesign.com/eg/buttons/3.0/code.html

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [MyCoolButton](http://www.mycoolbutton.com/), but styling is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few that I know of:

1. [Buttonator](http://www.buttonator.com/)
2. [My cool button](http://www.mycoolbutton.com/)
3. [As Button Generator](http://jirox.net/AsButtonGen/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac OS X, you could use [Button Builder](http://www.buttonbuilderapp.com/).

Also, although it's not as nice as generating your own button graphics, you could simply use the browser's default buttons:

```
<input type="button" value="My Button" />
```

Steve

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting into CSS you can generate something that looks like a winforms button:

```
.button {
    font:"Microsoft Sans Serif";
    font-size:small;
    background:#CCCCCC;
    border:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-left-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-top-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-right-color:#666666;
    border-bottom-color:#666666;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px
}
```

Or this which is meant to look like a key on a keyboard:

```
.key {
    font:"Microsoft Sans Serif";
    font-size:small;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#000000;
    border:solid;
    border-width:medium;
    border-left-color:#999999;
    border-top-color:#999999;
    border-right-color:#333333;
    border-bottom-color:#333333;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px
}
```

To use it just surround the text with:

```
<span class="button">Button Text</span>
<span class="key">Key Text</span>
```

I don't think I can post an example here, but if you look [here](http://www.chrisforman.me.uk/2009/03/album-shuffle-random-playlist-generator/) you can see it in operation.

I'll be the first to admit that they're fairly plain, but they do look something like a button ;) I'm sure a little tinkering with the CSS could give better results - particularly if you changed the colours.